# using pandas to create new columns based on intra-group rank-order

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy, pandas, aggregation

I have a pandas DataFrame with a large number of rows. I am trying to create new columns for the frame based on the intra-group rank-order of the members. Here is some fake data illustrating what I have:

```
Num_members = int(1.e7)
Num_groups = int(1.e5)
members = pd.DataFrame({
    'ID': np.arange(Num_members),
    'groupID': np.random.random_integers(0, 2*Num_groups, Num_members),
    'groupmass': np.zeros(Num_members), 
    'brightness': np.random.uniform(8,12, Num_members), 
    'color':np.random.uniform(0,1,Num_members)
})
```

I am trying to create two new columns for the *members*:

- The intra-group rank-order for the brightness, so that the brightest 
  member of a group would get a value of *0*, the next-brightest *1*, etc.
- The color of the brightest member of the group. So for this column, all members of the same group would be assigned the same value equal to the 'color' of the member with intra-group brightness-rank=0.

I know that the groupby operation is designed for exactly this sort of manipulation, but I haven't been able to figure out how to do this correctly. And speed is a significant issue, since my dataset is large and I need to do this within an MCMC likelihood analysis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll give it another try:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(42)
Num_members = int(10)
Num_groups = int(1)
members = pd.DataFrame({
    'ID': np.arange(Num_members),
    'groupID': np.random.random_integers(0, 2*Num_groups, Num_members),
    'groupmass': np.zeros(Num_members), 
    'brightness': np.random.uniform(8,12, Num_members), 
    'color':np.random.uniform(0,1,Num_members)
})
```

And the logic:

```
df = members.groupby("groupID").agg({"brightness": np.max})
df = df.reset_index()
df = df.merge(members[["groupID", "brightness", "color"]], on=("groupID", "brightness"))
```

First we do the grouping to find the maximum `brightness` value. After that we combine `df` with `members` to get the `color` value of the member with the highest `brightness` values. Basically, we combine all rows in `members` and `df` which have the same values of `brightness` and `groupID`.

Note that this may lead to unexpected duplication of rows, if there are multiple values with maximum score in a group.

`df` now looks as follows:

```
    groupID brightness  color
0   0   11.879639   0.139494
1   1   8.849356    0.366362
2   2   11.329771   0.292145
```

For each group it contains the `groupID`, the maximum value of `brightness` and the `color` of the element with the maximum brightness value.

We can now combine data frames `members` and `df`:

```
result = members.merge(df, on="groupID", suffixes=("_member", "_group"))
```

And get following result:

```
    ID  brightness_member   color_member    groupID groupmass   brightness_group    color_group
0   0   8.232334    0.304242    2   0   11.329771   0.292145
1   2   10.404460   0.431945    2   0   11.329771   0.292145
2   3   10.832290   0.291229    2   0   11.329771   0.292145
3   6   11.329771   0.292145    2   0   11.329771   0.292145
4   8   8.727300    0.456070    2   0   11.329771   0.292145
5   9   8.733618    0.785176    2   0   11.329771   0.292145
6   1   11.464705   0.524756    0   0   11.879639   0.139494
7   4   8.082338    0.611853    0   0   11.879639   0.139494
8   5   11.879639   0.139494    0   0   11.879639   0.139494
9   7   8.849356    0.366362    1   0   8.849356    0.366362
```

Comment: This is indeed *much* faster, cel. This definitely solves the problem of "find each group's brightest member". It is not quite what I was looking for, which was "find the *color* of the brightest group member, but all the same this is still very useful. I would happily upvote if you wouldn't mind just briefly explaining the logic behind this syntax, which is a little harder to follow than your first solution. (Likewise, I'd happily give an additional upvote to the color-question, but you've already been plenty helpful as it is).

Comment: @aph, and there's another update... it's getting more complicated, I guess... :D

Comment: I think it's cleaner to use `transform`, but unfortunately my tests show it's slower. :-/   I think the basic problem is that the balance of Python vs. Cython in the codebase is optimized for few groups with lots of members, not lots of groups.

Comment: @DSM `transform` instead of `aggregate`?

Comment: Yeah, to automatically perform a broadcast of the `max` up (for the reduced case where we were just trying to find out where a row had maximal group brightness; or maybe an `idxmax` if we needed to preserve the location).  But everything I tried along those lines was much slower than your approach..

Answer (score 2):

This is my toy example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
numpy.random.seed(42)
Num_members = int(10)
Num_groups = int(1)
members = pd.DataFrame({
    'ID': np.arange(Num_members),
    'groupID': np.random.random_integers(0, 2*Num_groups, Num_members),
    'groupmass': np.zeros(Num_members), 
    'brightness': np.random.uniform(8,12, Num_members), 
    'color':np.random.uniform(0,1,Num_members)
})
```

With a custom function that calculates the rank and the maximum value for brightness:

```
def rank_max_fun(df):
    df["b_rank"] = df.brightness.rank(ascending=False)
    df["b_max"] = df.brightness.max()
    return df
```

Grouping and applying

```
 df = members.groupby("groupID", sort=False).apply(rank_max_fun)
```

yields:

```
    ID  brightness  color   groupID groupmass   b_rank  b_max
0   0   8.232334    0.304242    2   0   6   11.329771
1   1   11.464705   0.524756    0   0   2   11.879639
2   2   10.404460   0.431945    2   0   3   11.329771
3   3   10.832290   0.291229    2   0   2   11.329771
4   4   8.082338    0.611853    0   0   3   11.879639
5   5   11.879639   0.139494    0   0   1   11.879639
6   6   11.329771   0.292145    2   0   1   11.329771
7   7   8.849356    0.366362    1   0   1   8.849356
8   8   8.727300    0.456070    2   0   5   11.329771
9   9   8.733618    0.785176    2   0   4   11.329771
```

Downside: It takes quite some time on large datasets.

Comment: elegant solution; this feels very natural. Your solution is also perfectly scalable to 1e6 members, but you're right that it's slow: 20s runtime when I ramp up Num_members & Num_groups.  It could be that the operation I require is just intrinsically expensive, because of the intra-group sorting. Although FOR loops I have written in straight-C to do the exact same task are about 10x faster than this, so I'm not sure what is the root cause of the performance hit.

Comment: So one thought along those lines is that I can probably do without the ranking of each member. All I really need to know is whether each member is brightest or non-brightest. So .idxmax may be a lot faster than a full rank-sort. Know how I'd use idxmax plus a custom function for the second column I asked about - the color of the brightest group member?